# how do I create Index for this SQL query? (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

my table field type set: (MyISAM)

```
`expired` tinyint(1) value:0~1
`site`    int(11)    value:0~3000
`area`    int(11)    value:0~1050
`endtime` bigint(13) value:timestamp(like:1285779723799)
```

I want run this SQL:

```
select * from `deal` 
  where `expired`=1 && `site`=17 && `area`=108 
  order by `endtime` DESC limit 0,10
```

how do I create Index for this sql is the fastest?

Comment: When it comes to indexes you generally want to index what you search against frequently.  Since you don't search against endtime you won't want to index this.  Also if you only search against a field here and there I would exclude that as well...I'm no sql expert, but has been my understanding of indexing practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you query included all columns... then try this:

```
alter table test add index idx1(site, area, expired, endtime);
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution....if you index everything you might as well have not indexed it (from my understanding)

Comment: Depending upon the usage of expired/endtime, they may be "overkill".

Comment: @Jared It depends on the query. The proposed index would "cover" the query conditional (but not necessarily the result set!). However, if the query was just looking for "expired" records, then *that* index would be useless ;-) There is indeed issues with over-indexing and, depending upon the data and usage, it might not be "best" to index over that much of it.

Comment: @pst  I agree I posted this as he has everything indexed after the alter statement even though endtime is not searched against as OP has listed currently.

Comment: @Jared The index could *potentially* also be used in the ORDER BY, although I am not sure how what the MySQL planner does here. Good call for pointing out it's not part of the filter, however.... sleepy eyes here.

Comment: thanks Xu, `alter table test add index idx1(expired, area, site, endtime)` which is better?

Comment: yeah, MySQL can utilize index to do ORDER BY.

Comment: `idx1(site, area, expired, endtime)` and `idx1(expired, area, site, endtime)` are the same?

Comment: @Zenofo it has to be checked in two perspectives. 1. your query pattern, you know one compound index can cover all the left-prefix columns. 2. if the 1st perspective is not your concern, then i think put the column whose value space the biggest at first, because it is more selective.

Comment: @James.Xu ,talk about 2, high selective or low selective put the first in compound  index? I think low selective should in the first(`expired` tinyint(1)),this is wrong?

Comment: @Zenofo By put the most selective column in the first, you can quickly minimize the result row count  -- less disk reading, less disk seeking.

Comment: @James.Xu,I optimized the sql to:`select id from deal ...`,only select `id` field,`idx1(site,area,expired,endtime,id)` or `idx1(expired,area,site,id,endtime)` which one should I choose?

Comment: @Zenofo，
when talking about index, the most import part is the where part，
so whether a index is used or not, good or bad depends heavily on the where